# Combine own stream with flagged user

Tags: views, flags

I am using follow flag latest version and edited the view fbss_ur_stream. I also created a following and followers view with the help of this tutorial [Twitter style follow following](http://ymbra.com/blog/allow-users-follow-each-other-views-and-flag-drupal)

I took the idea from it and implemented it in fbss_ur_stream view. I deleted the relationships and contextual filters and added the new ones. Relationship: Flag follow (current user) and (user) flag user & Cont. filter: (flag user) User: uid. I unchecked "only flagged content" as well as "require this relationship"

Now I am able to see the posts from the person I am following, but my posts are not showing. Why?

Do I have to clone it and create a new view within this master view? how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies with your contextual filter. It is set to filter the `uid` of `flag user`. This means it will limit the selection to only flags made by the current user (who did not flag himself, thus the user's own content is not selected).

You can probably solve this by having each user flag himself (automatically), but that is kinda ugly.

The alternative would be to use two regular filters and an OR group (remove the contextual filter). You might have to add some additional relationships if below steps do not work, but we basically want to have relations from the content to the user (author) and from the flag to the user (I believe you added that one already).

Add the filter `user: current` and select `yes` twice! For the first dialog, make sure you select the author relationship from content to user. For the second dialog use the flag to user relationship.

Finally, from the dropdown button above the filters section, select `And/Or Rearrange` and Create two groups with `Or` between them:

[image: filter]

Now make sure to place one of the filters in each group.

This should show all content where the author is the current user, or content where the author has been flagged by the current user.

Comment: great. Only removing the contextual filter "(flag user) user:uid" worked. Nothing else. For other readers let me clear that this is the view of "statuses" posts where you see your own stream only, by default.

Comment: can I show other content such as articles etc within the statuses stream? just wondering!

Comment: Theoretically you can. But it really depends on the way you setup the View. You need to have some relation to get the content in.

Comment: Can i add contextual filters and relationships within this view? or I have to create a sub-view or child view whatever you call it?

Comment: You can try and adapt this view any way you like. One View will always display on one page or one block, so if you create another View the content will not be in one stream. If you run into specific problems ask them as a new question, referencing this one in case it is relevant.